# Как предотвратить утечку памяти?

Tags: c++

```
char* operator-(){
    char *new_str = new char[strlen(str_)+1];
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str_); i++) {
        if (str_[i] != ' ')new_str[i] = (char) ((int) str_[i] - 32);
        else new_str[i] = str_[i];
    }
    new_str[strlen(str_)] = '\0';
    return new_str;
}
```

Как предотвратить утечку памяти в этом куске кода? Или её нет?

Comment: Сначала расскажите где именно вы видите утечку.

Comment: @PinkTux  Если бы он знал, он сказал бы. А так он спросил на всякий случай.:)

Comment: @PinkTux, моя логика проста и линейна. Если вижу new, обязательно должен быть delete. Или не так?

Comment: `delete` здесь не нужен, так как вы возвращаете `new_str`. А есть ли он где-то ещё - вам видней, местные телепаты вчера в отпуск ушли :)

Answer (score 2):

Как таковой, утечки нет.
Но - ваш оператор возвращает указатель на динамически выделенную память, и если вы его потеряете (просто не использовав это значение) или забудете освободить - вот тогда вы ее и получите.

Поэтому всегда лучше не возвращать просто указатель. Было бы лучше вернуть строку типа `string` - деструктор которой позаботится об освобождении памяти за вас.

Вот немного примеров для лучшего понимания:

```
char * f()
{
    char * q = new char[10];
    return q;
};



int main() 
{
    f(); // Утечка

    char * c = f();  // Утечки нет, но нужно помнить
    delete[] c;      // о необходимости удаления и делать это самому

    unique_ptr<char> s(f());  // Утечки нет - об освобождении 
                              // памяти позаботится unique_ptr
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Интерфейс вашей функции предполагает, что функция динамически создает строку и возвращает ее пользователю функции. Владельцем указателя является тот код, который вызвал функцию. Этот вызывающий код и ответственен за уничтожение полученной им из функции строки в случае ее ненадобности.

Другое дело, что функция написана, скажем так, не в лучшем стиле.

Во-первых, так как эта функция по всей видимости является функцией-членом класса, и она не изменяет сам объект класса, то ее лучше объявить с квалификатором `const`.

Так же непонятно, что означает магическое число `32`. Если это код пробела в таблице символов ASCII, то так лучше и написать символ пробела вместо данного магического числа. Если это не так, то лучше ввести мнемоническое имя для этого литерала, чтобы оно имело некоторое осмысленное для читающего ваш код значение.

В вашей функции три раза вызывается функция `std::strlen`.

Функция может выглядеть следующим образом

```
char * operator-() const
{
    size_t n = std::strlen( str );
    char *new_str = new char[ n + 1 ];

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
    {
        if ( str_[i] != ' ' ) new_str[i] = str_[i] - ' ';
        else new_str[i] = str_[i];
    }

    new_str[n] = '\0';

    return new_str;
}
```

Обратите внимание, что было бы ошибкой использовать эту функцию следующим образом

```
std::cout << -obj;
```

Где `obj` - это объект того класса, где определен этот оператор. В этом случае возвращенный из функции указатель будет потерян. Вам следует сначала присвоить его некоторой переменной. Например

```
const char *s = -pbj;
std::cout << -obj;
delete [] s;
```

Чтобы подобного рода проблемы не возникали, то лучше использовать стандартный класс `std::string` вместо указателей на символьные массивы.

В этом случае определение функции может выглядеть следующим образом

```
#include <string>

//...

std::string operator-() const
{
    size_t n = std::strlen( str );
    std::string new_str( n, ' ' );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
    {
        if ( str_[i] != ' ' ) new_str[i] = str_[i] - ' ';
        else new_str[i] = str_[i];
    }

    return new_str;
}
```

И тогда вы можете, не боясь утечки памяти, записать

```
std::cout << -obj;
```

Также рассмотрите вариант, когда оператор возвращает не просто строку, а объект вашего же класса. Например,

```
String operator-() const;
```

Тогда, так как, как я предполагаю, класс имеет соответствующий деструктор, то вы также можете смело писать

```
std::cout << -obj;
```

при условии, что вы определили оператор вывода `operator <<` для своего класса.

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ!
Единственное, что осталось непонятно:
- саму функцию я вызываю на вывод в поток (через cout), что при этом происходит с выделенной памятью?
//данный оператор метод моего класса String, ниже показан вызов функции
`String str;`
`cout << "operator-: " << -str << endl;`

Comment: Я так понимаю, что она магическим образом сама высвободится?

Comment: @Chad Если вы ее не удаляете, то происходит утечка памяти. Поэтому перед выводом в поток, вам надо сохранить в переменной возвращенное значение указателя и после удалить строку, используя эту переменную.

Answer (score 0):

*Утечкой памяти* называется ситуация, когда в вашей программе выделен блок динамической памяти, но впоследствии утеряна вся информация, позволяющая получить указатель на начало этого блока (в т.ч. с целью его освобождения).

Приведенный вам кусочек кода вырван из контекста настолько, что судить о том, есть ли в нем утечка памяти или нет - невозможно. В частности, если вызывающий код проигнорирует возвращаемое значение функции `operator-()`, то утечка памяти однозначно возникает. Если же вызывающий код сохраняет это значение, то утечки памяти формально не возникает.